# using contracts deployed by embark on the server side of a meteor app?

Tags: node.js, meteor, ethereum

I have created my example by `embark meteor_demo` and then changed my configuration on embark.yml to output the contract on the server folder instead of the client.

From that point i started getting some errors, which i described here: https://github.com/iurimatias/embark-framework/issues/138

Basically web3 wasn't defined on the server and after i add the web3 package from atmosphere it still undefined.

Any recommendation on next steps? Should i use the web3 project from npm and include it manually on the server?

Answer (score 0):

End up adding the same question on https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/791/using-contracts-deployed-by-embark-on-the-server-side-of-a-meteor-app sorry for the duplicate.

not sure if this thread should be deleted or kept here.